# SELECT and COPY row to another SHEET in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working on a Spreadsheet, and I'm up to the point of creating either a button or checkbox to SELECT and COPY a row to another sheet as part of an efficient archiving system. For e.g. the user will select their row, click the button and the row will be copied in the mentioned sheet. I'm still quite new to scripting in Google Spreadsheets as a whole. I personally wanted to head into the direction of using a button, but I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you all!

Comment: Generally most volunteers on this site like to see some code that you have done.   But in answer to your question you can add an image to your spreadsheet and click on the drop down that will be near it after it's inserted and you can attach a link to it that way.  Personally, I like to use a sidebar and build my controls with html and use the onClick events to communicate with Google Script.

Answer (score 1):

I think that works (you will be assigning a script/function to an image you upload, and then in the function use .getRow() on the active cell). Here is some advice that could save you some time. For your use case, instead of using a button, consider using the QUERY command:

You have a table in "sheet1" with some columns:

[image]

In that table you have an IMPORT column. You can use data validation on that column so that it is a Yes/No dropdown as well.

In a separate sheet, you write this which picks out all the rows with "Y":

```
=query(sheet1!A2:D1000,"select A,B,C where D='Y'",0)
```

And that will output this (minus the headings, which you can customize based on the last argument of the QUERY command):

[image]