# How do you count text from a cell in another sheet with Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, count

After researching for a solution on how to count text in a cell I've run into an issue and I'm unsure what's causing incorrect results or if I am not fully using this correctly.  In my research I've read and tested:

- [Counting number of occurrences in column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125847/counting-number-of-occurrences-in-column)
- [Need to be able to refer to a sheet within a count function](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/77823/need-to-be-able-to-refer-to-a-sheet-within-a-count-function)
- [How to fetch data from 2nd sheet in Google SpreadSheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346846/how-to-fetch-data-from-2nd-sheet-in-google-spreadsheets)
- [SELECT and COPY row to another SHEET in Google Spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244417/select-and-copy-row-to-another-sheet-in-google-spreadsheets)

Which suggest using `COUNTIF` and I can reference Sheet 1 named `foo` from Sheet 2 named `bar` using:

```
=COUNTIF(foo!$A$1,"$")
```

However, if the contents of Sheet 1 A:1 contain the text:

```
$1.00
$1.32
$13.98
$42.88
```

I'm looking for the count of times the `$` is present in a cell but when I use `=COUNTIF(foo!$A$1,"$")` it just returns 1.  When I click the help section on `Learn more about COUNTIF` I see where it shows `COUNTA` but now `COUNTA` only returns 2?

When I look up `=QUERY` it says for the range but I'm not looking for the range I'm looking for the total count of `$` in a cell.

In Google Spreadsheets how can I return the correct count of `$` in from Sheet 1 named `foo` from cell A:1 to Sheet 2 named `bar` cell A:1 so that if A:2 has 10 instances of `$` it will show 10 in Sheet named `bar` A:2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bar!A1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LEN(foo!A1:A5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(foo!A1:A5,"$",)))
```

It's common practice to just subtract length of substituted cell from the actual cell length to get count of the substitution string.

Comment: That's close what I needed was just `A1` not the range from `A1:A5`.  Also can you expand on what is happening?  Why did you choose `ARRAYFORMULA()` and then use it with `LEN()`?